# jquery mobile + phonegap onclick

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I've been trying to figure this out but still stuck.
so I'm using PhoneGap for iOS and JQueryMobile.
I'm trying to show alert when a button is clicked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">
        </script>
```

and I have
this

`<a href="#" id="button" data-role="button" data-theme="b">  Login </a>`


            `$(document).ready("#button").click(function() {
                                               alert('button clicked');
                                               });`

when I tried to launch this in chrome, this works fine.
however, when I used iphone simulator, it doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a normal web application you would use dom ready i.e.

```
$(function(){ // <-- this is a shortcut for $(document).ready(function(){ ... });
    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```

However in a JQM application it is much more useful to bind to 'pageinit' i.e.

```
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]',function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```

Binding to pageinit works better because JQM inserts new pages into the same dom as the first page. Because of this all of your code in dom ready doesn't get called again. So that first bit of code i put above will only work for that first page in your JQM application. The second will work no matter what page your button is in. Let me know if I can clarify this further for you.

Comment: thank you, I figured the problem was actually the newest PhoneGap version. I then used PhoneGap 1.5 and it works fine.

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind.

so I have this index.html and login.html and I use a href to link from index to login.
and in each index.html and login.html I import the javascript.
However, it seems that only the ones come from index.html that is being loaded.
so if I place the js in index.html for the login.html, it works fine.
but then, we I place it separately ( another js for login.html that is not in index.html) , it doesnt work.

Comment: i think this would be best asked as a new question, rather than in a comment